# Moving Average formula in Excel not autofilling in table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

so I recently created an excel table to track my weight and I wanted to create a 7 day moving average column.

The problem I'm facing now is that the Moving Average column isn't autofilling when I create a new entry. I created the Moving Average formula using this guide:https://www.deskbright.com/excel/rolling-average-in-excel/ which included using the data analysis option

Here is the moving average formula:

[image: Here is the moving average formula]

The problem is that when I create a new entry, like this

[image]

the Moving Average formula doesn't autocomplete, whereas the Average Weight formula does.
In the image, the 6/28 and 6/29 entries for the 7 Day Average column are empty. The Formula showing is for the Average Weight, based on a normal 7 day week, not rolling.

I realize it's pretty simple to just drag the formula down to fill it out, but is there any way for it autocomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the formula to autofill, you could use `AVERAGEIFS`, with `COUNTIFS` to ensure that you only return a value if the table includes the proper date range for a 7-day moving average:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&A2-6,A:A,"<="&A2)<>7,"",AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&A2-6,A:A,"<="&A2))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow this is amazing. Is there any way you could breakdown what each part of the formula means? I generally understand what COUNTIFS AND AVERAGEIFS do, but the syntax like  A:A,">="&A2-6 is kinda confusing, I've never seen it written this way before. Nonetheless, the formula works! Do you know why the previous formula I was using wouldn't autofill? Thanks so much.

Comment: Yes. The [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-calculated-columns-in-an-excel-table-873fbac6-7110-4300-8f6f-aafa2ea11ce8) should be helpful for understanding how calculated columns work. I think the approach you had doesn't work because you can't actually enter the formula as you would want it in the first row. The `A:A,">="&A2-6,A:A,"<="&A2` is just a way to say "all days that are within the 7-day period ending in" and whatever date is in A2.

Comment: For a more thorough explanation, all dates within that seven date range will satisfy two criteria: they will be 1) greater than or equal the last day minus six days, and 2) less than or equal to the last day. So basically `A2-6` and `A2` are the first (earliest) and last (latest) days in the 7-day range.

Comment: I see, that really clears it up. And the `<>7` means if those 2 criteria are not met in 7 days, then BLANK, otherwise `AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&A2-6,A:A,"<="&A2)`?